# Who was the subject of the fallen statue in Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, a large statue was used to crush an opponent. More precisely:

> [During Earth-838's Captain Marvel's fight with the Scarlet Witch](https://www.cbr.com/scarlet-witch-captian-marvel-victory-doctor-strange-2-mcu-theory/), the aforementioned statue fell on [Maria Rambeau](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maria_Rambeau_(Earth-838)).

[image: screencap of described statue]

Who did this statue depict?

Comment: Is there a spoiler tag for post headlines?

Comment: @DoscoJones: No, there is not.

Comment: I've seen theories that it was of Jocasta but I'm not convinced that the appearance is the same.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Doesn't look like Jocasta to me. Looks a lot more like Xena: Warrior Princess, as per the [current answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264930/122024). Also, it's not obvious why the Illuminati would have a giant statue of Jocasta, from either an in-universe or out-of-universe perspective, whereas Xena makes sense as an out-of-universe nod to Sam Raimi.

Comment: @LogicDictates I didn't say it WAS Jocasta, just that I've seen theories, Personally, I'm doubtful as stated.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I understood what you said, and was agreeing with you that those theories are likely mistaken. I saw that claim myself while googling, hours before I read your comment.

Answer (score 22):

It is indeed supposed to be Xena from *Xena: Warrior Princess* which Sam Raimi developed. It is just an out of universe Easter egg. I can't confirm it since I don't have access to it but in the audio commentary for *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* Raimi and Palmer talk about the statue.

> **Raimi:** That was patterned after Xena. And I think it was your idea. The great Lucy Lawless. This scene pays tribute to female heroes and villains.
>
> <sub>[Quote taken from this tweet](https://twitter.com/landeath/status/1541440962156806145/photo/4)</sub>

I can't find the rest of the quote but [this article by startefacts](https://startefacts.com/news/did-you-spot-that-xena-easter-egg-in-multiverse-of-madness) confirms that this is just meant as an Easter egg and nothing more.

> Yes, the iconic Xena, played by Lucy Lawless, did make an appearance in an MCU movie! Years ago Sam Raimi produced the series for 6 seasons, and he certainly looks back fondly on his time working on the fantasy saga, sneaking this important reference into a huge Disney blockbuster. However, this does not mean that Xena is now an MCU canon and a member of the Multiverse's Illuminati – Raimi confirmed that this is just a fun Easter egg with no narrative subtext.

Comment: Oh, if a producer of *Xena: Warrior Princess* says a reference has no subtext, it must be so.

Comment: See also: Lucy Lawless's brief cameo in Raimi's first *Spider-Man* movie as a punkish "random person on the street" giving an approving opinion of the titular hero.

Comment: I didn't think it made sense for Captain Marvel to be killed by a falling statue; surely flying through Thanos's battleship requires more strength than having a statue land on you.  Maybe Xena the Warrior Princess is her version of Kryptonite.

Answer (score 6):

[On IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9419884/trivia?item=tr6368007), they say it's Xena:

> When Wanda is in the main lobby preparing to fight against Mr. Fantastic, Captain Carter, Captain Marvel and Black Bolt, you can see a large female statue in the background [SKIP SPOILER]. This statue is Xena from Xena: Warrior Princess (1995). A TV show that Sam Raimi developed and was executive producer on.

Comment: It does resemble Xena, and the Sam Raimi connection makes sense, out-of-universe. Would be nice to have confirmation from an official source though.